# Cannot resolve dependencies when trying to install gnome-libs or xscreensaver on linux

Tags: linux, installation, gnome, dependencies, xscreensaver

I am a linux noob and am trying to install ORacle10g on RHEL5 but am running into difficulties on the requirements stage. The only 2 packages I require is gnome-libs and xscreensaver.

I have downloaded both:
'gnome-libs-1.4.1.2.90-44.1.i386.rpm
'xscreensaver-4.18-5.rhel4.11.i386.rpm'

But when I try to install them I get dependency errors. I have been trawling sites and forums for 2 days now and am no closer to resolving this and continuing with my Oracle install.

To pre-empt possible trouble-shooting questions, here is a list of the dependcies that could not be resolved:

For gnome-libs:
libdb.so.2(GLIBC_2.0)
ORBit
libdb.so.2
libllOP.so.0
libORBitCosNaming.so.0
libORBitutil.so.0
libORBit.so.0
libpng.so.2
And it says all the above is needed by package 1:gnome-libs-1.4.1.2.90-44.1.i386(/gnome-libs-1.4.1.2.90-44.1.i386)

For xscreensaver:
xloadimage is needed by package 1:xscreensaver-4.18-5.rhel4.11.i386(/xscreensaver-4.18-5.rhel4.11.i386)

Sorry if I have explained this in a crap way - like I said - linux noob here. Any help with this would be great, its been a long 2 days so far - i need to get this resolved soon.

Thanks

Comment: Where did you download Oracle 10g from ? And what edition is this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install libgnome, libgnomeui and libXp with `yum install libgnome libgnomeui libXp`

That should be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Stop trying to install RHEL 4 packages on a RHEL 5 system. Use `yum` to install the libraries you need instead.

Comment: I have tried using yum but with no success. Due to my inexperience I might be using it wrong - any chance of a quick example of the commands to use to install these 2 packages via yum? I have already tried but just in case I am doing it wrong. Thanks

Comment: The reason you can't install these packages via yum because they don't exist in RHEL 5 in the first place. You need to back up and figure out what you *really* need.

Comment: OK but I cant seem to find a RHEL5 version of either - I have downloaded the most recent versions i could find.